# std::out_of_range basic_string when going to the next element from an empty string in vector

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have a `std::vector<std::string>` that holds separate strings at each index. Each `row` represents a new string and each `column` represents the `(index + 1)` of a character in the string.

If I insert an empty string in a specific row (starting at 1), by doing:

```
lines.insert(lines.begin() + row, "");
row++;
column = 1;
```

This means if I inserted the empty string at row 2, my vector looks like this:

```
{ "Hello", "", "World" }
```

But, if I move from row 1 ("Hello"), to row 2 (""), by doing

```
row++;
column = 1;
```

I get the error:

```
terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string
```

The same error happens if I move from row 2 to row 3, so moving to a row with a valid column doesn't work.
This error doesn't happen if I don't have an empty string though. If I have anything put into the new string that is then inserted into the vector, I can use `row++;` without error.

Comment: The error indicates that you access an invalid character of your string. The string has a zero-based index. How do you access the elements? Show that part of the code.

Comment: The two lines `row++; column = 1;` will not cause that error. I suspect you're indexing the string using `column` rather than `column - 1` somewhere, or your vector is broken.

Comment: Run in a debugger, break on the exception, examine the current line and variables' state.

Comment: @molbdnilo going to check everything out. I could be using column wrong since it is in use in a few functions. I'll also try using a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have the answer to your problem. Upon closely reading your post, it seems that you are inserting into positions 1, 2, and 3 of the **vector**.

A **vector** works like an **array**. I won't go into details of the implementation of the **vector** but what you need to take note of is that **arrays start from index 0**.

Now, you also need to understand how `vector.begin()` and `vector.end()` works. `vector.begin()` works like a **pointer** that points to the **first element** of the **vector**. `vector.end()` works like a **pointer** that points to **one after the last element** of the **vector**.

Since `row` starts from 1, what you're doing is inserting into ***one after the first element** of your **vector** when you perform `lines.insert(lines.begin() + row, "")`. Therefore, your **vector** becomes like this:

`{ <uninitialized string>, "Hello", "", "World" }`

Thank you for reading.